# HttpClient PostAsync cancels request

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have a fairly trivial case where I want to upload a file to a service called CloudConvert.com

I use a multipart form to do so, there is even an example of how to use multipart forms from html on their API console:

This is their example:

```
<form action="https://api.cloudconvert.com/convert" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="hidden" name="apikey" value="banana-my-key">
<input type="hidden" name="inputformat" value="pdf">
<input type="hidden" name="outputformat" value="docx">
<input type="hidden" name="input" value="upload">
<input type="hidden" name="wait" value="true">
<input type="hidden" name="download" value="inline">
<input type="submit" value="Convert!">
</form>
```

This is my corresponding c# code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{                
    formData.Add(new StreamContent(paramFileStream), "file" );
    formData.Add(new StringContent("banana-my-key"), "apikey" );
    formData.Add(new StringContent("pdf"), "inputformat" );
    formData.Add(new StringContent("docx"), "outputformat" );
    formData.Add(new StringContent("upload"), "input");
    formData.Add(new StringContent("true"), "wait");
    formData.Add(new StringContent("inline"), "download");
    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.cloudconvert.com/convert", formData,new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2000)).Token);
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
}
```

This code fails with the exception:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operation canceled. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Operation canceled
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal.<FillBufferAsync>g__InternalFillBufferAsync|38_0[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adap, ValueTask`1 task, Int32 min, Int32 initial)
at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal.ReadAsyncInternal[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection
```

Inside Cloudconvert, I can see that they report that they are waiting for the upload.

What am I doing wrong here, it seems like the StreamContent is not being streamed in the request the way it should be.

Any obvious problems here?

ps. putting their html example inside a html file and uploading that way works fine.

Comment: do you see the exception when you use PostAsync without cancellationToken paramter?
Have you tryed to send the same request over SOAP UI? What are the results?

Comment: Does it work if you do not include the cancelation token?

Comment: From this discussion on Twitter: https://twitter.com/timbabyuk/status/1101080182356533248

"Looks like combo. If CloudConvert don't see the file data (which is required), why they redirect to get converted file? They had to throw bad request. I think the reason could be in some low-level details of GET request generated by HttpClient which is not correctly handled by CC"

Comment: In the past, I have had problems with the using blocks in specific scenarios. Is it possible that the client and content objects are getting disposed too early?